# How to receive layer data features in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geoserver-geofence

I'm developing module in GeoServer that needs Layer feature members. 
I can get it easily with WFS request like this

```
ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:layer&maxFeatures=50
```

But I need to achieve it internally in GeoServer(I mean something like this *`catalog.getFeatureMembersByName("workspace:layer")`*)

I know that I can send request in GeoServer internally but I don't think that is proper way. I don't want to talk directly with database because I need in this module GeoFence features.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (might need minor corrections) should work:

```
FeatureTypeInfo info = catalog.getFeatureTypeByName(getLayerId(MockData.BASIC_POLYGONS));
SimpleFeatureSource fs = (SimpleFeatureSource) info.getFeatureSource(null, null);
try(SimpleFeatureIterator fi = fs.getFeatures().features()) {
    SimpleFeature sf = fi.next();
    System.out.println(sf);
}
```